# Use decltype inside template parameter list to deduce the type of pointer to class member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc

GCC is giving me a "template argument 2 is invalid" error when I try to instantiate a template like this (see `using Check` line). I was very curious that I can get a pointer to member using `decltype` outside of a template parameter list, but not inside one (see definition of variable `p2`). And indeed Clang did compile this code. Is this a bug in GCC, or this code is actually invalid and Clang is just being too inclusive?

```
template <class T, T t> struct checker_template {};

struct S { int n; };

int main() {
  S s;
  constexpr auto p1 = &S::n;
  constexpr auto p2 = &decltype(s)::n;
  using Check = checker_template<int S::*, &decltype(s)::n>;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you chose not to include the full error from GCC?

Comment: Bug, already fixed in trunk.

Comment: @kfsone it was literally the only meaningful information.

Comment: @T.C. you should probably post your comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by T.C. This is indeed a bug in GCC.